# Finding Sets of 3 pairs in list that form a Circular reference

Tags: python, list

Hopefully a really simple question but I have been pulling my hair out over this.

I have a list of reference points that have been identified through an index. These index values are the start and end points of lines. *EG Line 1 [1,3] Line2 [4,5] etc*

I attempting to do the following in Pure Python and have run through so many code iterations I cant think straight anymore. I am sure it is a list management solution of some sort...

```
**List 1:**

[1,3]
[4,5]
[2,1]
[5,1]
[3,2]
[4,1]
```

From List 1 I wish to get the following output.

```
**List2**
[1,3]
[2,1]
[3,2]

**List3**
[4,5]
[5,1]
[4,1]
```

So the result is groups of data that effectively provide a circular/triangular association between them.

Please help, I am totally stumped!

EDIT:
I have attached a sketch of the data structure I am working with. You can see each line has a start and end point reference. And identifying the corresponding "groups" within the list to be able to extract 3 unique references would allow me to generate a triangle.

[Link to Data Structure Example and Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alFn1.jpg)

I have abandoned most of my code to date but have tried using combinations (I dont want to use this method because there will be lots of data to iterate through)

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    for indices in permutations(range(n), r):
        if sorted(indices) == list(indices):
            yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)

input = IN[0]
result = []

for i in input:
    matrix = []
    matrix.append(combinations(i,3))
    result.append(matrix)

OUT = result
```

Comment: Where is the code that you had tried?

Comment: What happens if you have a circular association of more than 3 elements? What about the same for the *triangular* association, could there be more than 3?

Comment: I'm not sure I see the pattern. What is `list1`, exactly? A list of tuples? What do you mean by "circular/triangular association"? Do you want `list2` to contain the first, third, fifth... Elements of `list1`, and `list3` - the second, fourth and sixth...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this? We basically just check each pair of adjacent vertices to see if they have any common neighbors, if so then that forms a triangle. We arbitrarily enforce some ordering on the points (`x < y < z`) so that we don't find the same triangle more than once.

```
# given some input:
pairs = ([
[1,3],
[4,5],
[2,1],
[5,1],
[3,2],
[4,1]
])

# compute the set of neighbors of each vertex
from collections import defaultdict
neighbors = defaultdict(set)
for x, y in pairs:
  # enforce some arbitrary ordering x < y < z so that
  # we don't find the same triangle more than once
  if x < y:
    neighbors[x].add(y)
  else:
    neighbors[y].add(x)

# for each pair of adjacent neighbors
for (x, y) in pairs:
  # Optional sorting
  if x > y:
    (y, x) = (x, y)

  # (x, y, z) form a triangle if z is a common neighbor of x and y
  common_neighbors = neighbors[x] & neighbors[y]
  for z in common_neighbors:
    print((x,y,z))
```

Producing the set of triangles (not quite in the same format that you mentioned, but should be the same information content, feel free to adjust accordingly depending on your requirements):

```
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 4, 5)
```

Comment: This worked, i just needed to tweak the data structure slightly. Very grateful Flight Odyssey. This is a fix for generating surface triangles for a Delaunay set of lines.

Comment: Great, glad to help!